# Ubuntu in vbox guest. How to setup manual DHCP?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, dns, dhcp

I am in Windows 10. I have virtual box with Ubuntu.
I want to have static IP address.
This is the ipconfig of the Windows 10 (host):

`Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::19db:7da2:425a:a6e3%19
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.11
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1`

This is the configuration in the guest Ubuntu machine:

[image]

This way I have no Internet.

If I set it to "Automatic DHCP" it working, but the IP is dynamic.

How can I set it to static IP address?

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest that you try an address of 10.0.0.7, netmask 255.255.255.0, gateway of 10.0.0.1 and DNS of 10.0.0.1. Does it connect?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Are you trying to see your VM through the Ubuntu?  Do you want your VM on the same network as the host?  As it stands your question is unclear.

Comment: @Terrance - the win10 is the host, the ubuntu is the guest. ubuntu has samba in, and im sharing the files to windows. I need a steady IP address for the ubuntu so i would be able to access the files via network share.

Comment: When you revert to DHCP, what to the respective addresses look like?

Comment: The gateway needs to be on the same subnet as the network client, i. e. the client IP address needs to start with the octets 192.168.1.